# ReactDOM Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm sorry to ask such a specific question but I'm working on a simple tutorial which introduces React with the following HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hello Separate</title>
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello Separate</h1>
    <div id="app"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And a script to create a `<p>` within the `div id ="app"` using ReactDOM

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <p>Rendered by React</p>,
    document.getElementById("app")
  )
```

[I've provided the code in a fiddle here:](https://jsfiddle.net/MayaGans/6uz2v1cf/4/)

I don't understand why I'm getting the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` but think it's coming from the `ReactDOM.render` function, can anyone provide insight? Thank you!

Comment: [JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html) isn't available by default in the browser, so you either need a build step (something like create-react-app which provides configuration for most common setups) or you use the React api directly `React.createElement`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Two issues with your code,**

**First**

Your scripts are not proper. As per [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html), you should add these scripts,

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
```

**Second**

Might be you are writing your `JS` code in external `JS` file.

From the docs,

> Now you can use JSX in any `<script>` tag by adding type="text/babel" attribute to it.

You need to add this `script` in your `HTML` file only,

```
<script type="text/babel">
  ReactDOM.render(
    <p>Rendered by React</p>,
    document.getElementById("app")
  )
</script>
```

[Demo](https://jsbin.com/wutanoduko/edit?html,output)

Comment: Didn't know about babel in the browser, though there's [a reason why it's uncommon](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#quickly-try-jsx): _"This approach is fine for learning and creating simple demos. However, it makes your website slow and isn’t suitable for production."_

Answer (score 0):

yes you might be right, you will might need to change: `<p>Rendered by React</p>` to either `'<p>Rendered by React</p>'` or `"<p>Rendered by React</p>"`

like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    "<p>Rendered by React</p>",
    document.getElementById("app")
  )
```

you have to always enclose text or html in ".."

Answer (score 0):

As Emile Bergeron mentioned you're actually writing JSX, so you need 'build'
 or transpile the code in regular JavaScript.

However if you're using just JSFiddle, they can transpile the code for you like this.

[image: transpile]

If you're working locally you can look into create-react-app as they mentioned or babel and webpack to build/bundle your files.