# Couldn't display react on html

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I was trying to display my first code on the screen through React, but I didn't work as I was expected, It was nothing, and I think the problem was I called incorrect the name of element.

```
JS
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
ReactDOM.render(<p>Hello</p>, document.getElementById('root'));

HTML
<body>
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="js-index.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: could you share more info like the exact error message and some more info about the project setup?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReactDOM Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57385785/reactdom-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token)

Comment: Have you checked your index.html ? Please share folder and file structure along with their code. Though above code is enough to display Hello.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a relative path witth a ./ in front of the file name?

```
<script src="./js-index.js"></script>
```

Also what are you using to transpile react code to regular javascript code? Can't comment 1 rep away :/ . Reply back and Ill be happy to help!